# Algorithms for Physically based shading models

Tags: graphics

For real time interactive graphics, it seems to be practical now to use physically based shading models. I want to write some shaders to incorporate into an openGL based game engine that I'm writing and I wasn't sure of what algorithms to read up on. What algorithms and models seems to be practical and useful for real time graphics as of 2014?

Comment: Plus you're confusing algorithms with mathematics, which is probably why your prior research didn't turn up many answers before you came here.